# simple picture carousel jquery

Tags: jquery, image, slider, carousel

I'm trying to implement a simple image carousel that infinitely changes the banner picture of my site.

This is what I have so far:

```
function bannerSlider() {

        setInterval(function() {

            if ($(".pictureBanner img").hasClass("activePicture")) {
                alert("fired");
                $(".pictureBanner img").removeClass("activePicture");
                $(".pictureBanner img").next().addClass("activePicture");
            }
    }, 4000);   
}

$(document).ready(bannerSlider);
```

When implemented, this changes the first picture but then stops firing (the alert is in here for me to see that the function actually fired).

I'm relatively new to web developement, but this seems like it should work in theory.

Any tips would be amazing, thanks.

EDIT: html markup added below.

```
<div class="pictureBanner"><img class="activePicture" src="img/img1.jpg"></div>
<div class="pictureBanner"><img src="img/img2.jpg"></div>
<div class="pictureBanner"><img src="img/img3.jpg"></div>
```

EDIT: after all the wonderful help from you guys, I got it to work. Below is the final code:

HTML

>

```
<div id="bannerPictures">
  <img class="activePicture" src="img/img1.jpg">
  <img src="img/img2.jpg">
  <img src="img/img3.jpg">
</div>
```

<

JS

> function bannerSlider() {

```
    setInterval(function() {  
        var img = $("#bannerPictures img.activePicture");
        var next = $(img.next());
        next.addClass("activePicture");
        img.removeClass("activePicture");
        if (next.length === 0) {
            $("#bannerPictures img").first().addClass("activePicture");   
        }

}, 4000);
```

> }
>
> $(document).ready(bannerSlider);

Comment: show your html markup. `alert` is not a very good debuggung mechanism, learn how to use console logging

Comment: Added just now. Thanks for the alert tip, I'll bear that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function bannerSlider() {

    setInterval(function() {    
        var img = $(".pictureBanner img.activePicture");
        img.removeClass("activePicture");
        var next = img.parent().next().find("img").addClass("activePicture");
        if(next.length ==0){
            img = $(".pictureBanner:first img");
            img.addClass("activePicture");
        }
    }, 4000);   
}

$(document).ready(bannerSlider);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pictureBanner"><img class="activePicture" src="img/img1.jpg"></div>
<div class="pictureBanner"><img src="img/img2.jpg"></div>
<div class="pictureBanner"><img src="img/img3.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does the exact same as what my original code does; changes the picture once, then stops. I'll add the html in my original post to see if there is something wrong with the markup.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, `$(".pictureBanner img")` has no siblings, only `$(".pictureBanner")` has. So I suggest to wrap all images in 1 div with the pictureBanner class.

`$(".pictureBanner img").next().addClass("activePicture");` adds the `activePicture` class to **every** element that is a sibling of `.pictureBanner img`. So not only to the image that is a sibling of the one with the `activePicture` class. By storing this one in a variable you get the effect you actually want. I created a Codepen here: http://codepen.io/lutsen/pen/wBGMYE

Another problem with this code is that it doesn't loop if there is no more sibling. Now it just stops when the last image is reached.

JS:

```
function bannerSlider() {

        setInterval(function() {

          activePic = $(".pictureBanner img.activePicture");
          activePic.next().addClass("activePicture");
          activePic.removeClass("activePicture");

    }, 1000);   
}

$(document).ready(bannerSlider);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pictureBanner">
  <img src="image.png" alt="" class="activePicture"/>
  <img src="image.png" alt="" />
  <img src="image.png" alt="" />
  <img src="image.png" alt="" />
  <img src="image.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I see. Edited the html and it now cycles through the images until the last one and stops. Thank you for the reply! :)

Comment: I accepted the answers, but it won't let me up vote since I don't have any reputation yet :(